# Need help generating an algorithm that converts json object into a specific structure

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm

consider json object like so

```
var data = {
   keyA: [ {keyA0: [keyA00]} ],
   keyB: [ {keyB0: [keyB00]} ]
}
```

more visually its like so

```
-keyA
  - keyA0
      - keyA00
-keyB
  - keyB0
      - keyB00
```

need to convert that into something like so

```
var convertedData = {
   name: root
   children:[
              {name:keyA, children: [ {name: keyA0 : children: [{name:keyA0, children: []}]} ]},
              {name:keyB, children: [...]}
            ] 
}
```

The "..." is the recursive structure, until it hits a leaf node in which the children is an empty array.

Comment: In your example, the arrays all have exactly one element - would real data potentially have multiple (or zero) elements? As an aside, [there's no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: yes, so for example keyA0 could have [keyA00, keyA01, ... , keyA0N]. It could also be the case that KeyA0 holds an empty array of childs

Comment: In your exact example, it would be impossible, seeing as `convertedData.name;` can only hold one value. If `convertedData` was an array, then the solution could more-easily be solved with recursion.

Comment: Should your `convertedData` be an array rather than an object? It doesn't have `keyB` but does have `keyB0` as a child of `keyA`, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with JSON... it's all JavaScript objects (well, kind of).

Comment: I just came back and looked at this again. Wouldn't each element in each `children` array also need to be an array of objects? Because in the source `data` object each property is an array of objects and each of those objects might have multiple properties the same way that `data` does (even though that is not the case in your example).

Comment: @everyone, yea sorry for the bad example,, I've updated the example to better show the  recursive pattern. Hopefully it is more clear now

Comment: What if the inner objects have more than one property just like `data` does? Something like the following: `keyB: [ {keyBa0:[keyBa00], keyBb0:[keyBb00]}, {keyB1:[keyB10]} ]`

Comment: it should be converted into `{name: keyB: children: [{name:keyBa0:children:[{name:keyBa00:children:[]}]}, {name:keyBb0,children:[{name:keyBb00,children:[]}]}]}` and so on for keyB1

Comment: "and so on" is too vague, because (in my example) `keyB1` is a child of `keyB` but it is a separate object to the other child of `keyB` that has two properties `keyBa0` and `keyBb0`. (Also, a given array could, hypothetically, contain sibling objects that re-use the same property names, e.g., in my previous example `keyB1` could've been `keyBa0`.)

Comment: All child would be encapsulated in the "children" property. So in you example, it would be {name: keyB: children[ {name:keyBa0: children:[...]}, {name:keyB1: children: [...]} ]. I'm not sure what the confusion is. btw, thanks for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, maybe it will become use to someone else with similar problem. Here is the js fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/tF3uH/20/, and for further reference the code

```
var data = {
    "KeyA": ["KeyA0", "KeyA1"],
    "KeyB": [{"KeyB0": ["KeyB00", "KeyB01"]}] 
};
/* EXPECTED OUTPUT
[
{name: KeyA: children:[{name:KeyA0, children:[]},
                       {name:keyA1, children:[]}
                      ]
},
{name: KeyB: children:[{name:KeyB0, children: [{name:KeyB00, children: []},
                                               {name:KeyB01, children: []}
                                              ]
                       }
                      ]
}
]
*/
function _doConversion(jsonData, treeList) {    
    if (typeof jsonData == typeof Object()) {
        $.each(jsonData, function(key, val) {
            var isArray = Array.isArray(val);
            var name = key;
            var children = [];
            if (isArray) {
                $.each(val, function(i, item) {
                    _doConversion(item, children);
                });
            }else{ //not array but object
                _doConversion(val,children);
            }
            treeList.push({
                name : name ,
                children: children
            });
        });
    } else { //a leaf (could be string,number,boolean...)
        var node = {
            name: jsonData,
            children: []
        };
        treeList.push(node);
    }
}

var list = [];
_doConversion(data, list);
$("body").text(JSON.stringify(list, null, "\n"));​
```